# $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin{\varphi} \ e^{jka\sin{\varphi}} \ d\varphi$ =?

Tags: integration, special-functions

Could you help me solve this integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin{\varphi} \ e^{jka\sin{\varphi}} \ d\varphi
\end{equation}

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a Bessel Function.

Comment: See the connection with the Bessel integrals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel's_integrals

Comment: I saw it but I still get stuck in that integral.

Comment: According the Bessel definition $\displaystyle J_0(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ix\sin\tau}\, d\tau$ and after differentiation 
$$\dfrac{2\pi}{i}J'_0(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin\tau e^{ix\sin\tau}\, d\tau = 2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin\phi e^{ix\sin\phi}\, d\phi$$
then
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin\phi e^{ix\sin\phi}\, d\phi=-\pi iJ'_0(x)=-\pi i\left(-J_1(x)\right)=\pi iJ_1(x)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Cylindrical Bessel function  $J_0(z)$ is defined as $$J_0(z)=\pi^{-1}\int_{0}                                                             ^{\pi} \cos(z \cos x) dx ~~\mbox{and}~~ J'_0(z)=-J_1(z) = - \pi^{-1}\int_0^{\pi} \cos x~ \sin(z \cos x)~ dx~~(1). $$Denote the given integral by $I$. So,
$$I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin x ~ e^{iz\sin x} dx= \int_{0}^{pi/2} \sin x ~[e^{iz \sin x} -e^{-iz\sin x}] dx=2i \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin x ~\sin(z \sin x)~dx.$$ Next use $$\int_{0}^{a} f(x)~dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) ~dx$$
To get $$I=2 i \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos x ~\sin (z ~\cos x)~ dx.$$
Now use the symmetry property  $$2\int_{0}^{a} f(x)~ dx= \int_{0}^{2a} f(x) ~dx, ~~\mbox{if}~~ f(2a-x)=f(x)$$
Then $$I=i\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos x  \sin(z \cos x) dx =i \pi J_1(z)~~\mbox{see (1).} $$
Hence the answer is $i\pi J_1(z).$

Comment: Thank you so much!